# Can MongoDB be accessed without Driver over JSON REST API

Tags: mongodb

For some reason I don't want to use MongoDB standard driver.

Would it be possible to talk to it via REST HTTP with plain JSON? I know it has Atlas, but it seems Atlas is for the complicated, large scale cloud deployments. I don't need cloud and large scale installation, I need local MongoDB instance with very simple setup I can talk via REST API.
Is that possible?

Comment: No, MongoDB has no web interface.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thanks, but I would call it HTTP or REST interface, not Web.

Comment: No, MongoDB has no HTTP/REST interface. You can use Atlas also for easy small deployments, (would be even for free)